# What is audio fingerprinting? And how to counter it?

Tags: privacy, fingerprinting, audio-fingerprinting

1. What are websites methods of collecting audio fingerprint? Is it by JavaScript or Java applets or flash plugin?
2. How to counter it?
3. Does it work on Android?

Comment: Websites and apps need access to the microphone to do any time of audio capturing and chrome will do the permission per domain meaning you can counter it just by revoking access to the microphone.

Comment: Do you have any source on that?

Comment: I added some sources in the answer, you could probably get a more complete answer posting on the security stack exchange [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/). Just be sure to read their page on [how to ask a good question](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

## You can block them with permission settings

For websites there might be a security risk when using lesser known or less secure browsers. But Chrome for example allows you to manage permissions per domain or stop it all together:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2693767?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en
https://ccm.net/faq/30701-prevent-websites-from-accessing-your-camera-and-microphone-on-google-chrome

On Android apps, apps need to explicitly ask for microphone access before recording anything:

https://www.avg.com/en/signal/guide-to-android-app-permissions-how-to-use-them-smartly
https://www.psafe.com/en/blog/prevent-apps-using-microphone/

If your concern is purely about your own security, the links I shared have steps for managing your privacy.